# Restructure list items into groups

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, data-structures

I have a List which contains items like this:

```
{ 
 Answer: "test answer",
 FaqTopicName :"General",
 Question: "test question",
 SortOrder: 0
},

{ 
 Answer: "...",
 FaqTopicName :"General",
 Question: "...",
 SortOrder: 1
},

... (repeated)
```

I wish to restructure the List so that it now contains each list item grouped inside of an object. The result object will look like the following, and will contain all items which have the same FaqTopicName under the property name "items" = [].

The format of data I wish to end up with:

```
{
  topicName: "General", 
  items: { 
         Answer: "test answer",
         Question: "test question",
         SortOrder: 0
        },
        { 
         Answer: "...",
         Question: "...",
         SortOrder: 1
       }
}
```

Here is what I have tried, but it doesnt come out correct and also will not run through JavaScriptSerializer():

```
List<FaqQuestionAnswer> allFaqItemsInSelectedSytem = faqController.GetAllFaqItemsForSystem(out errors);

var groupedData = (from qaItem in allFaqItemsInSelectedSytem
                   group qaItem by qaItem.FaqTopicName
                   into questionsAnswersGroupedDataset
                          select questionsAnswersGroupedDataset).Distinct().ToDictionary(items => new { title = items.Key.ToString(), items = items.ToList() });
```

Resulting in this in the debugger:

[0] = {[{ title = EBooks, items = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JPay.Base.FaqQuestionAnswer] }, System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,JPay.Base.FaqQuestionAnswer]]}

but when I run it through the JSON converter it throws type errors:

Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXX],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Base.FaqQuestionAnswer, Version=1.0.6180.30742, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX]], tttwebsite, Version=1.0.6181.25360, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXX],[ttt.Base.FaqQuestionAnswer, tttBase, Version=1.0.6180.30742, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't come out correct", what data format are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is here:

```
.ToDictionary(items => new { title = items.Key.ToString(), items = items.ToList() });
```

You probably think you are defining a dictionary with `Key = items.Key.ToString()` and `Value = items.ToList()`, but in fact the `ToDictionary` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) you used has the following signature:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

hence you are converting the result to some strange dictionary having anonymous type `{ string title, IEnumerable<FaqQuestionAnswer> items }` as a key and `IGrouping<string, IEnumerable<FaqQuestionAnswer>>` as a value.

If you really need dictionary, then you should use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

like this:

```
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Also note that `Distict` after `GroupBy` is redundant.

To get the exact format you described, you can use simple `GroupBy` with custom `Select`:

```
var groupedData = allFaqItemsInSelectedSytem
    .GroupBy(e => e.FaqTopicName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        topicName = g.Key,
        items = g.Select(e => new { e.Answer, e.Question, e.SortOrder }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var groupedData = 
    (from e in allFaqItemsInSelectedSytem
     group e by e.FaqTopicName into g
     select new
     {
        topicName = g.Key,
        items = (from e in g select new { e.Answer, e.Question, e.SortOrder }).ToList()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. I am not able to get that result to convert to JSON either, seems to still have the same issue this way

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this, which gave me the results I needed:

```
    protected string GetJPayWebsiteFaqTopics()
    {
        // call the FAQ manager
        var faqController = managers.GetFaqManager();
        string errors = string.Empty;
        string result = string.Empty;

        // All items returned from faq manager, 2d collection not grouped into topic dictionaries
        List<FaqQuestionAnswer> allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem = faqController.GetAllFaqItemsForSystem(out errors);

        // Storage for main data, prior to serialization
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> allFaqTopicsAndItems = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        // Group all item Lists together in alike topic related faq items
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, FaqQuestionAnswer>> groupedData = from qaItem in allFaqItemsInSelectedSystem
                                                                        group qaItem by qaItem.FaqTopicName;
        // Allow the groupData to get iterated 
        IGrouping<string, FaqQuestionAnswer>[] enumerableGroups = groupedData as IGrouping<string, FaqQuestionAnswer>[] ?? groupedData.ToArray();
        JavaScriptSerializer jsonConverter = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        foreach (var instance in enumerableGroups)
        {
            // Each group of data should have a title for the group, a list of FAQ items
            var items = instance.ToList();

            // Temp storage for each topic and associated faq item data
            Dictionary<string, object> group = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            /**
             * Temp storage for clean faq items stripped of topic level data which has now 
             * been added to the parent node so no longer needed at this level
             */
            List<QuestionAnswerOrderOnly> cleanedItems = new List<QuestionAnswerOrderOnly>();

            // Add the group title
            group.Add("Title", instance.Key);

            // Add the topics display order to the group data 1st item since it is on every item
            group.Add("TopicOrder", items[0].TopicOrder);

            /**
             *  Pull the values that are important for the item only, add it to the group 
             *  Clean up item before recording it to the group it belongs to
             */
            cleanedItems.AddRange(items.Select(item => new QuestionAnswerOrderOnly(item.Question, item.Answer, item.ItemOrder)));

            // Add the clean faqitems collection
            group.Add("Items", cleanedItems);

            // Add this topic group to the result
            allFaqTopicsAndItems.Add(group);
        }

        jsonConverter.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

        try
        {
            result = jsonConverter.Serialize(allFaqTopicsAndItems);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            result = $"{errors} {error.Message}";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and output the following:

```
{
  topicName: "General", 
  items: { 
         Answer: "test answer",
         Question: "test question",
         SortOrder: 0
        },
        { 
         Answer: "...",
         Question: "...",
         SortOrder: 1
       }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else that is in a similar situation.